# Is it Possibles to Get a KeyPath from a CodingKey?

Tags: swift, swift4, keypaths

Is there a way to get a `KeyPath` to a property using a `CodingKey`? Or maybe there is some other way that would work that doesn't involve `CodingKey`s. That is fine also.

Incase it helps, I only need to be able to read a value with a `KeyPath`, not write to it.

I am pretty sure someone will want to suggest a manually created computed property like this:

```
var keyPath: AnyKeyPath {
    switch codingKey {
        case ...: return \Self....
    }
}
```

That isn't what I am looking for. I would like a solution that figures this out automatically.

Comment: "I need to loop through a types properties and set a dictionary value with the value of the type's property." What do those words mean? Please give an example of sample input and desired output.

Comment: @matt I think I added what you want.

Comment: No, this isn't currently possible. You might be able to create a [`Mirror`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror) from their type to do what you want, but it's not currently possible to get all the `KeyPath`s of a given type. Potentially in the future, though!

Comment: Not really, no. This reads like an x-y problem. I still don't know what you _really_ are trying to do, and you are hamstringing yourself and us by believing that this (whatever "this" means) is how to do it (whatever "it" is). If you want to turn an arbitrary JSON dictionary into a Swift dictionary, use JSONSerialization.

Comment: @matt I know there are different ways to do JSON serialization, but is it wrong for me to do it in a odd esoteric way? I know the usual "don't use this in production...", but it is amazing what you can learn sometimes by doing things that you "shouldn't".

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" for you to do, if it works for you. I'm responding to the question as a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: See https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery. Directly through introspection, no.

Comment: One of you could just answer 'No' and get the rep .